# I made a C++17 burrito for mapping over tuples, and anything that has begin() end() iterators. Is it possible to get rid of these factory functions?

Tags: c++, tuples, monads, implicit-conversion, c++17

I found myself needing to iterate (generically) over an array, or a tuple of N T's.

Code demo:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b8ab7c01b79d086

I came up with the following implementation, which I'm reasonably happy with it, as it seems to to handle the cases I need without introducing any overhead.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

namespace functional
{

namespace detail {

template <typename Tuple, typename F, std::size_t... Indices>
void
tuple_for_each_impl(Tuple &&tuple, F &&f, std::index_sequence<Indices...>)
{
  using swallow = int[];
  (void)swallow{1, (f(std::get<Indices>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))), void(), int{})...};
}

} // ns detail

template <typename Tuple, typename F>
void
for_each(Tuple &&tuple, F &&f)
{
  constexpr std::size_t N = std::tuple_size<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>::value;
  detail::tuple_for_each_impl(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple), std::forward<F>(f), std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

} // ns functional

struct tuple_tag {};
struct iterator_tag {};

template<typename U, typename TAG>
struct burrito
{
  U value;
  using TAG_TYPE = TAG;

  template<typename T>
  burrito(T const& t) : value(t) {}

  template<typename T>
  burrito(T t0, T t1) : value(std::make_pair(t0, t1)) {}

  template<typename FN>
  void iterate(FN const fn) const
  {
    bool constexpr IS_TUPLE = std::is_same<tuple_tag, TAG_TYPE>();
    if constexpr (IS_TUPLE) {
      functional::for_each(this->value, fn);
    } else {
      for (auto it{value.first}; it < value.second; ++it) {
        fn(*it);
      }
    }
  }
};

template<typename M, typename FN>
void testfn(M const& m, FN const& fn)
{
  m.iterate(fn);
}

template<typename T>
auto
make_burrito(T t0, T t1)
{
  auto const p = std::make_pair(t0, t1);
  return burrito<decltype(p), iterator_tag>{p};
}

template<typename C>
auto
make_burrito(C const& c)
{
  return make_burrito(c.cbegin(), c.cend());
}

template<typename ...T>
auto
make_burrito(std::tuple<T...> const& t)
{
  using U = std::tuple<T...>;
  return burrito<U, tuple_tag>{t};
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// demo
int main()
{
  std::tuple<int, int> const tup0 = std::make_tuple(-3, -4);
  std::array<int, 10> const arr0 = {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14};
  std::vector<int> const v = {32, 42, 52, 62};

  auto const m0 = make_burrito(tup0);
  auto const m1 = make_burrito(arr0.begin(), arr0.end());
  auto const m2 = make_burrito(v);

  auto const fn = [](auto const& i) {
    std::cerr << std::to_string(i) << "\n";
  };

  std::cerr << "printing tuple\n";
  testfn(m0, fn);
  std::cerr << "|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-" << "\n";

  std::cerr << "printing array\n";
  testfn(m1, fn);
  std::cerr << "|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-" << "\n";

  std::cerr << "printing vec\n";
  testfn(m2, fn);
  std::cerr << "|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-" << "\n";
}
```

I'd like to be able to hide the instantiation of the burrito from the caller entirely, but still define my function arguments as a burrito.

Like this:

```cpp
template<typename B, typename FN>
void something(B const& burrito_like, FN const& fn) {
  burrito_like.iterate(fn);
}
```

With the caller doing:

```cpp
auto const tup = ...; // somehow caller creates a tuple
something(tup, []() {});
```

This doesn't work though (obviously) and the compiler complains about tuple not implement iterate(FN const&);

I looked into implicit conversion constructors, but I don't see how I would specify the different TAG parameters from within the implicit constructor.

**So my question is**, is something like this possible?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to remove the invokation of `make_burrito`?

Comment: Yes, I'd like the caller to be able to pass in a tuple or an array or a vector directly to functions who's inputs are just a generic template type, and use that as a burrito. The assumption here would be the compiler would see the caller passing in a tuple, sees the function accepts a type that's used like a burrito, and instantiates the burrito from the user's tuple argument, automatically. My intent is that the implicit constructor would be called on the tuple to convert it to the appropriate burrito type. Does that make more sense?

Comment: ... what is a "burrito" in this context?

Comment: Giving your tag type member functions is.. bizarre. Make `iterate` a free function, give it the tag as an argument, and let it specialize on the tag.

Comment: @NicolBolas http://blog.plover.com/prog/burritos.html

Comment: The OP posted a non-answer with a link to an answer: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93a91a9da85a5171